# Statistics and reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

I ended up on the page of danielovich (https://stackoverflow.com/users/76152/danielovich).

First of all: nothing (negative) about this guy.

He has a reputation of 497 and behind this the text "top 26% this quarter".

How can this be?

**EDIT**

My mistake. I was confused about how this system works. First I was confused because my page shows statistics for just a week, other user pages show them for longer periods. I also was not directly aware that those stats were about growth, not about the endscore of your reputation.

Comment: What is the problem? There are a lot of users so it is easy to be in the 25% for a quarter if you really try.

Comment: Well, earning 67 rep this quarter brings him in the top 26%. Where's the problem?

Comment: That's reputation leagues, did you try clicking the "[top 26%](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2013-04-01/76152#76152)"?

Answer (score 2):

The *vast* majority of users on SO have 1 reputation.  They come, either don't do anything, or ask one or too questions that aren't good enough to even get an upvote.

There are also a lot of users that come and just ask one or two questions, so even if they get a few upvotes here or there, won't get to 497 reputation.

Getting even a few hundred reputation, as you've seen, by just being active at all for a short period of time is enough to put you in the top quarter of new-ish users.

Comment: For what it's worth, my dinky little reputation score puts me in the top 9% overall. That's a **long** tail.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow has millions of users. Many of them are not that active. So he made it in the first quarter of users. Nothing special about it.

You don't need that much reputation to be more active than most users.